What is the correct way to keep container out of the flow until clicking a button to show that container?
I am struggling with keeping containers out of the flow until i click a button to show them. Maybe its a fundamental thing . In this example , when i click on any of the category of : MEN , WOMEN , KIDS , im displaying 5 links and an svg , but i want to have a transition for smoothness. The problem is that im using display none and transitions dont work with displayenter image description here
In the following example , I am going to show the code for the links for simplicity. so the subgenderman, subgenderwomen, subgenderkids are the ul for the links and is displayed to none , until the man,women,kids is checked , the display will be flex .


.subgenderman,
.subgenderwomen,
.subgenderkids {
  transition: 2s;
  display: none;
}


/* Show subgender when the 'men/women/kids' radio button is selected */

#men:checked~.subgenderman,
#women:checked~.subgenderwomen,
#kids:checked~.subgenderkids {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  align-self: center;
}
<ul class="gendersection">
  <li><label for="women" class="gender-label">WOMEN</label></li>
  <li><label for="men" class="gender-label">MEN</label></li>
  <li><label for="kids" class="gender-label">KIDS</label></li>
</ul>

<!-- Hidden radio buttons  FOR MEN WOMEN KIDS-->

<input type="radio" name="gender" id="women" class="gender-radio">
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="men" class="gender-radio">
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="kids" class="gender-radio">

<!-- MAN LIST LINKS -->
<ul class="subgenderman">
  <li><a href="#">TrendingM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ClothingM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">AccesoriesM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ShoesM</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SportM</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- WOMAN LIST LINKS -->
<ul class="subgenderwomen">
  <li><a href="#">TrendingW</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ClothingW</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">AccesoriesW</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ShoesW</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SportW</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- KIDS LIST LINKS -->
<ul class="subgenderkids">
  <li><a href="#">TrendingK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ClothingK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">AccesoriesK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ShoesK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SportK</a></li>
</ul>




Please describe what transition effect you want and what you have tried to achieve it. For example, does the sublist gradually expand/shrink in height as it's selected/deselected or does the deselected list fade out as the selected one fades in?

i want the text to appear after like 1s , not as soon as i press one of the category , or i want the text to appear like it came from the left side

You need to be specific about the transition required, and you have to ensure that the element to be transitioned has a start point and an end point, with the end point set on the relevant input/label being clicked. You also need to be specific about how the element transitions out when another list is selected.

I would caution against waiting a second before the user gets any feedback that their click has been seen - that is long enough for them to wonder if something has gone wrong and so they might click again, another second pause etc.

You can use display:none with opacity:0. Transitions are not applied to display but they apply to opacity. when user clicks on radio buttons first set display and then set opacity to 100.
Hope this helps...

even with opacity there isnt a transition happening

Instead of display:none use max-height:0  and opacity:0 and when clicked add properties opacity:100 and max-height:100px adjust the max-height accordingly.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The simplest solution would be adding animation with keyframes. It will work with display: none too, below is working example.
You can customize animation as per your like and if you want more delay in text then increase animation-delay. Here animation is setting opacity: 0 to opacity: 1 and keeping it at "1" with help of forwards in animation.
If I have misunderstood or missed something do share.


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainDiv {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.yourText {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: 1s fadeIn forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
<h2 class="mainDiv">
  Other Text
  <div class="yourText">
    Clean Code Editor
  </div>
</h2>



